# Configuring Jersey Via XML?

Tags: maven, jersey

Is it possible to configure Jersey via XML rather than annotations? Here's my issue:

I have a maven multi-module project with the following modules:

- client
- webservice
- shared

In the shared module, I would like to put my basic POJO classes, with minimal dependencies in the Maven POM. The webservice module will require the POJOs to be configured for both Hibernate and Jersey (such as with @XmlRoot and @Entity annotations). The client module has no need for the Hibernate- and Jersey-specific configuration, and having the classes annotated would introduce the dependencies into the client POM.

Normally I actually prefer annotations over XML, but in this particular case I'm trying to keep the design modular and at least somewhat clean.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the classes and mark hibernate and jersey as [optional dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies). Then the classes are annotated appropriately and your client is free from the extra dependencies.

Comment: That's probably a 90% solution, but if I can avoid the clutter in the POM I'd like to do that as well. From what I'm finding, though, that's probably the best I'm going to do.

Comment: Is it clutter? It clearly expresses that this project doesn't require but optionally supports integrating with Hibernate and JAXB.

Comment: I ended up creating a "shared" module that didn't have the classes, but interfaces. This let me use AutoBeans on the GWT client side, and implement the interfaces on the server and annotate there. Result: clean separation between the client and server sides, no hibernate/jackson/jersey dependencies on the client side, no GWT dependencies on the server side.